# How to transform element with XMLNS attribute

Tags: xml, transformation, xml-namespaces, xdt-transform

I am trying to transform child element of another element that contains `xmlns` attribute, but seems my transformations are ignored until I remove `xmlns`.

So let say I have:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          internalLogLevel="Trace"
          internalLogFile="NLogInternal.log"
          autoReload="true">
        <targets>
        </targets>
    </nlog>
```

And I am trying to get rid of `targets` element with:

```
<nlog>
    <targets xdt:Transform="Remove" />
</nlog>
```

But that doesn't seem to work, however if I remove `xmlns` and `xmlns:xsi` attributes transformation work as expected.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `xmlns` attribute defines a default namespace. You have to declare it assigning a prefix *in your XSLT* to that namespace (ex: `ns1` by using `xmlns:ns1="..."`), and refer to the elements using the prefix (ex: `ns1:targets`). You can also try selecting it using an XPath expression without a namespace (`*[name()='targets']`)

Comment: Note: `xdt:Transform` is quite specific to Microsoft web.config.  You should probably tag the question with the `xdt` tag to bring in experts in that area.

Comment: Search for "XSLT default namespace" and you will find about 500 answers to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will work, but try the following:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">
    <targets xdt:Transform="Remove" />
</nlog>
```

By placing the `xmlns` attribute on `nlog`, you are specifying that you are targeting the `{http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd}nlog` element, and the `{http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd}targets` element within it.

Also, you may want to do some research on XML namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `targets` element you need to consider its namespace. You can either *declare* the namespace with a prefix in your XSLT, which you should use in the template match XPath expression to eliminate the `targets` tree:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xmlns:ns1="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()"> <!-- Copies all nodes to result tree -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ns1:targets" /> <!-- Ignores this node -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or completely ignore the namespace. In this case you don't have to declare but you must use an XPath expression selects all elements but restricts by its local name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[name()='targets']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm assuming the example you posted. If you have other `target` elements in other contexts and namespaces, you might have to deal with that differently.

Comment: Unfortunately, the OP mis-tagged the question as [tag:xslt]. He's actually using xdt transforms.